# Eclipse: MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I've just installed Eclipse Helios version 3.6.1 on my Windows 7 64 bits machine.
But, when I want to open Eclipse MarketPlace I get this error:

MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error.

```
Unable to read repository at 
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&os=win32&runtime.version=3.6.0.v20100505&client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&java.version=1.7.0_07&product.version=1.3.2.20110218-0812&ws=win32. 
Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
```

Any solution please?

Comment: I found a solution to this issue. Check this post for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74450091/4180447

Answer (score 30):

You can solve u r problem like this,
In Eclipse IDE go to Windows --> preference --> General --> Network Connection --> Select Active provider to Direct --> Apply --> Ok.

Comment: Thank for the quick help.

Comment: Mine is already set to Direct and it used to work but now it isn't working.

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, after " Selecting option Active provider to Direct"

Answer (score 14):

The only way I could fix this was by importing the certificate into "cacerts"

here are the steps to follow:

- copy the link that eclipse is having problem to access, by using details button, then paste it to google chrome browser and press enter.

in my case link was:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.21

- just beside the link in your browser there is Lock icon, hover over it, should show "view site information"
- click on the lock icon -> click on "connection is secure" -> click on "certificate is valid" and a dialog called "certificate" should pop up.
- go to the tab "details" and click on the button "copy to file..."
- follow the export wizard steps to export certificate file (.CER)
  Export the file on format "DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER)"
- save the file to desktop with name "marketplacecert.cer"
- now copy this certificate file to the folder where the jre is located
  in your eclipse folder installation

  in my case:
  C:\eclipse-cpp-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149\jre\lib\security

  in this folder you should find a file called "cacerts", where we gonna import the certificate through "keytool.exe"
- now open CMD prompt and go to the folder:
  cd C:\eclipse-cpp-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149\jre\lib\security
- we gonna have to use a tool called "keytool.exe" to import the certificate file, which is located at:
  "C:\eclipse-cpp-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149\jre\bin"
  two folders up from our current location, to execute it we gonna use the relative path ....\bin\keytool.exe

  run the following command on CMD prompt:
  ....\bin\keytool.exe -import -alias alias -keystore cacerts -file marketplacecert.cer

  keytool.exe will ask for a password, which is "changeit"

  keytool.exe will ask to trust the certificate, type "yes" and press enter.

  done.
  Now restart eclipse and marketplace should be working.

  Refer to this link for more details:
  https://thebasictechinfo.com/java-8/pkixunable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-fix/

Comment: this is exactly the correct way to solve this problem (y)

Comment: software field is making "things very easy".

Answer (score 13):

i had the same problem
the sulotion was to copy my ...security/cacert from my JRE and then paste it in my eclipse  .....\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507\jre\lib\security (replace cacert of the eclipse by cacert of JRE)

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand why Eclipse has it's own cacerts and not using the JDK/jre cacerts file?

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work for me with eclipse ide 2021-12

Comment: JRE cacerts patha in macos:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security


Below is the eclipse cacerts path in mac:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-sa-1.8.0_232.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.macosx.x86_64_15.0.1.v20201027-0507/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 3):

Verify you can reach that URL by command line or so.
If you are connected with VPN, disconnect VPN and try again. It works for me.

Comment: Disabling my vpn helped me connect to the Market Place - THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your pc cann't connect to the http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&os=win32&runtime.version=3.6.0.v20100505&client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&java.version=1.7.0_07&product.version=1.3.2.20110218-0812&ws=win32

You can set a network proxy on Windows--> Preferece --> Network connection.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it occurs when you download **Eclipse Standard 4.3.1** . You have to download **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall current version of Java. Go to www.java.com, download recommended version of java. After successful install. Verify java installed (located on home page - www.java.com). Should work then... Mine did.

Answer (score 1):

Add below args :

> -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

to the end of the eclipse.ini file and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in an organisation try to ask your colleague developer that have an active marketplace for there casert.cer file and replace it in your jdk

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, I did face the same issue. Here is the fix**

**Problem**:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.21.0.I20210906-0500
    java.version=16.0.2
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product 
    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core
**Error**
Thu Sep 16 13:07:14 IST 2021
Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.21: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.stream(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
```

**Solution:**

```
In order to resolve this issue, I copied my security/cacert file from my JRE (java-se-8u41/jre/lib/security/cacert) to my eclipse (/eclipse/../jre/lib/security/cacert) e.g. /eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149/jre/lib/security/cacert
```

**Reference:**
For more detail and step by step guide along with screen-shots, you may refer the following url : https://thebasictechinfo.com/java-8/pkixunable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-fix/

Enjoy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, edit the config.ini file located in the Eclipse installation directory/configuration folder and modify the following line:

- If `"com.genuitec.pulse.delivery.mpc.include.patterns"` exists, then modify it to:

  `com.genuitec.pulse.delivery.mpc.include.patterns=^https://marketplace.eclipse.org.*`
- If it doesn't exist then simply add this line in the end of config.ini file:
  `com.genuitec.pulse.delivery.mpc.include.patterns=^https://marketplace.eclipse.org.*`

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating the certs as others suggest, but they just become outdated and then the same problem repeats itself.

What you have to do on windows is to configure java to use the MS cert store, instead of javas.

So in the same directory as the eclipse.exe, find eclipse.ini. In it find the line:

```
-vmargs
```

and on the lines just after that, insert

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

Save the file and then restart Eclipse.

Reference:
[SSL and cert keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/ssl-and-cert-keystore)

Answer (score -1):

We just had the same problem and apparently the answer TODAY is just wait it out.. This is for anyone experiencing this problem in modern 2020.03 versions of Eclipse.. Its a problem from Eclipse's servers that are sometimes not reachable.. Just wait an hour or so and try again later.. It should work as long as it has worked before of course..

Comment: I can access from the browser, so the server is available.