# Is there a durable solution to SSL certificate validation for Eclipse plugins?

Tags: eclipse, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore, eclipse-marketplace

Each time I want to install a new plugin from Eclipse marketplace or an update site, I have the error message 'PKIX path building failed' and I had some degree of success solving this issue by downloading the certificate manually from Chrome and installing it to the JDK's cacerts file with the keystore command. This ended up having like 30+ certificates downloaded and installed manually.
We can see that this solution is not durable :

1. For some plugins, the URL references another location, which references another one, which can end up in downloading and installing 2-3 certificates for 1 single plugin
2. For Eclipse marketplace, the certificate seems to be valid only one day. If I download it and install it one day, I have to redo the same thing the next day or I get 'PKIX path building failed'.

I had a look at this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214663/8315843

Peter suggests to input the full path of cacerts to the eclipse.ini file as well as the keystore password :

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/full/path/to/cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

I tried that solution.
In fact I expected that because I gave a password, I would have an automatic certificate validation but this is not the case. Instead I got the same error message 'PKIX path building failed' again and I had to rerun the keystore command manually after re-downloading the certificate manually.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at this solution if it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66602754/15831887 also you can try to install new software to help instead of the marketplace