# Eclipse. MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error

Tags: eclipse, certificate, keytool, eclipse-marketplace

[image]

PFA. Unable to open eclipse market place with  error:

```
MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.19: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: You tagged your question with `proxy`, but your question does not say anything about a proxy. Why?

Comment: hi,  I doubt it to be  issue with proxy cz on trying directly install eclipse from the installation file I see that "the catalog couldn't be loaded, Please ensure that you have n/w access and , if needed have configured your n/w proxy"

Comment: When it's not your proxy, it's the Java with which you run Eclipse. Unfortunately your question does not contain information about the proxy used and Java used, so one cannot say why it does not work in your Eclipse, which is one release behind. Did you know, you can simply copy an entry from the _Error Log_ into your question containing some information about the Java used?

Comment: hi, I have downloaded the zip installation files and I have mentioned that I am unable to open Eclipse Market place in Eclipse, the issue could be with the proxy, I tried changing the n/w settings to manual, native ,default . yet no luck. So , I have attached the error.

Comment: What type of proxy are you using and what Java are you running Eclipse with? Please edit your question and paste the entry from the _Error Log_ view into your question (in Eclipse select the entry and hit Ctrl+C). Currently, your question contains only the error message which is not enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the client machine and this error is resolved once I added the windows->preference->N/w connection in General settings--> Made the provider manual and edited http and https with the client added authentication and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when accessing the Eclipse Marketplace, I just had to install the certificate on my Local Machine according to the Eclipse Marketplace (Path) where the Eclipse had Failed then MAKE SURE TO REBOOT YOUR PC ONCE IT IS INSTALLED.

Following are the steps to perform this task:
I find it easier to use the browser "Edge" as an example to get the certificate from the url had failed.

1. Open Edge with the url that had failed on: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.19
2. Click on the Lock Icon URL then click on the Connection is Secure
3. From the Connection is Secure link then click on the Certificate Icon as per below:
   [image: Certificate from the browser]
4. From the Certificate Viewer window, click on the Details TAB then Export the  _.eclipse.org.crt into your PC or Desktop then right click on the .crt file to install it.
   [image: Install the Certificate]
5. From the Certificate Import Wizard, select the Store Location to "Local Machine" then click Next
6. Leave as Default "Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate" then click Next
7. Click Finish.
8. Make sure to Reboot your PC then Launch Eclipse
   (Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace, no error should appear now)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could not open Eclipse Marketplace and got the same error reported in the question of this thread. I was able to solve this problem by getting instructions from the admin since I am connected using VPN. If I disconnect the VPN, it will work without any problem. I am using Eclipse `Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0) - Build id: 20220908-1902`.

## Steps (Windows):

1. Get the certificate definition files and store them under this folder for example: `<user-home>\.certificate\my-certs.pem`. If you have more than one certificate, combine the definitions in this file `my-cert.pem`. In my case I was provided two certificates, they are `XXXROOTCA` and `XXXCERTnn`.
2. If you have more than one certificate, store each in a separate file in the same folder for example `file1.crt` and `file2.crt`.
3. From the command line with admin rights, use the Java `keytool` to import the certificates:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -import -alias XXXROOTCA -file %HOME%\.certificates\file1.crt -cacerts
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -import -alias XXXCERTnn -file %HOME%\.certificates\file2.crt -cacerts
```

Note: Make sure to associate the certificate alias with the correct file in the above command lines.
3. You may have to pass the password for the above command lines. Add the parameter `-storepass changeit` if the password is still `changeit` and you didn't change it which is the default.

4. For NodeJS, execute the following command (if required):

```
setx NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS %HOME%\.certificates\my-certs.pem
```

Now you should be able to open Eclipse Marketplace.