# Change default .keystore location

Tags: java, jvm, keystore, keytool

How to make JVM search for .keystore file in user specified location instead of deafult location (user's home directory)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore

Comment: Is this question about the `keytool` command?

Comment: Keytool is used to create keystore files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing an ant build you should just parameterise the `SignJar` task by setting the `keystore` parameter.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about SSL then

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path
```

Comment: I am trying to build a project using ANT build, but the JVM looks for the .keystore file for the project in C:\Users\Gopakumar and not in the project directory. I want to make JVM looks for the keystore file in my project directory.

Comment: Use `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit` for the password