# Configure Tomcat to prefer one signer over another OR use different certs per endpoint?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I have a Spring Boot (v1.3) web service running Tomcat 8 with endpoints that hit multiple downstream services.  Each downstream service requires information in the user's certificate that was signed by that downstream service's CA.

A user will have all of the certs they need (a cert for each of the necessary CAs), but the service needs to obtain a different cert for each endpoint.  Is there a way to do that (get a specific or all certs from a user's browser)?

(Maybe something along the lines of grabbing the tomcat SSLSessionManager (org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLSessionManager) in the appropriate controller and invalidating the session/ca...and asking for a different one..)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want : have multiple tomcat endpoints the user can connect to, or call multiple endpoints from your tomcat.

If this is the first one, then you can either:

- declare multiple tomcat connectors, each with its own keystore
- or add a front server (like Apache, Nginx, HAProxy, etc.) that will handle the SSL part given a requested DNS

If this is the second solution you need, you can have one keystore with all certificates.This keystore can be registered to the JVM through the `javax.ssl` properties. See [java SSL and cert keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore) for more information

Comment: I would like to obtain different certs from the user's browser based on the endpoint.  I'm hoping to not create different connectors because I don't want a user to have to use different ports.

Comment: Then using a front is an easy way to do that :)