# How to explicitly add arguments to Java web client app?

Tags: java, eclipse, soap-client, java-ws

I have created a Web Service client in Eclipse (java) from wsdl but when I try to run it by providing user credentials it gives me

```
HTTP transport error : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
java.security.cert.CertificateException: 
No subject alternative names present
```

I googled and found that I need to explicitly add

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
```

arguments to client application. Sorry for dummy question, could someone please explain how I can add them?

Comment: How do you execute your java program client ? Prefer from command prompt and you will understand how to add `-DXXx`. You can get help from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a program from Eclipse, you can provide your arguments here :

[image]