# Getting jav ax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when doing docusignapi handshade

Tags: java, json, ssl, docusignapi

I am getting a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` when using the DocuSign API handshake.

Trying to use the DocuSign API login samples gives a cert error.

The following code is a sample from DocuSign. It sets up a Signer and DocuSign Configuration object.  When doing the `setDefaultApiClient` call, the error is generated.

> Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: jav
>               ax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKI
>               X path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcepti
>               on: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle
>       (URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
>       at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.getAPIResponse(ApiClient.java:563)
>       at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:595)
>       at com.docusign.esign.api.AuthenticationApi.login(AuthenticationApi.java:156)

**Added**

```
// initialize the api client ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();  
apiClient.setBasePath(BaseUrl); // create JSON formatted auth header   
String creds = "{\"Username\":\"" + UserName + 
   "\",\"Password\":\"" + Password + "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" +
   IntegratorKey + "\"}"; 
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", creds);
System.out.println("assign api client to the Configuration object ");
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient); }
```

Comment: Here is the code used to implement the docusign api call

Comment: // initialize the api client
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
apiClient.setBasePath(BaseUrl);
// create JSON formatted auth header
String creds = "{\"Username\":\"" +  UserName + "\",\"Password\":\"" +  Password + "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" +  IntegratorKey + "\"}";
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", creds);
System.out.println("assign api client to the Configuration object ");
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just as a tip, you can edit your question so that all of your code is in the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I copied your comment into your question.

Comment: Please remember to upvote all useful answers (including those to others' questions), and to "check" the answer that best solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

"unable to find valid certification path" means that you need to set up your Java stack with the "standard" set of trusted root certs.

What's happening: you're trying to make an SSL connection to DocuSign. As part of the SSL process, your machine has to determine if it trusts the far end (DocuSign in this case) or not.

To do so: your SSL stack tries to build a trust path from its trust store of root CA certs to the cert offered by DocuSign. But it can't since you haven't set up your trust store properly.

The usual "standard" set of trusted root certs are the ones that the Mozilla Firefox browser uses.

See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

How to load them into your Java stack as trusted certs is stack-dependent.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore) looks relevant but I'm not a Java guy. Ask another question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I have added this to my cacerts store in my jre directory

Comment: Added this to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts store.  Also added demo.docusign.net.crt, DocuSignCodeSigningPublicCertificate.cer, sso.docusign.net.crt to my cacerts store under my jdk.

Calling my code with 
java -jar costco-docusigntest.jar -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake

Getting the following error.
Exception in thread "main"

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: jav
ax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKI
X path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcepti
on: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.
..
      at com.costco.docusign.CoreRecipes.main(CoreRecipes.java:1061)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.Validator
Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPath
BuilderException: unable t .