# jarsigner -verify: warning messages - BouncyCastle signed jar

Tags: jar, bouncycastle, jarsigner, jar-signing

This is new domain for me so not entirely sure how to interpret the available information.

Research yields the following relevant posts:

[Version 1.50 + WebStart: signature not verified](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Version-1-50-WebStart-signature-not-verified-td4656642.html)

[java SSL and cert keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore)

However, still not sure if this is noise or if I am lacking configuration in my  JVM or JDK environment.

Do I conclude that these files are valid and safe to use?

What do I need to do to eliminate the warning messages?

My question is how do I interpret the following messages that are generated by this command:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs bcmail-jdk15on-157.jar
```

Generates the following output:

```
  s      11224 Thu May 11 17:31:18 EDT 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  X.509, CN=Legion of the Bouncy Castle Inc., OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Sun Microsystems Inc
  [certificate is valid from 3/10/17 8:15 PM to 4/25/20 3:00 AM]
  X.509, CN=JCE Code Signing CA, OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Sun Microsystems Inc, L=Palo Alto, ST=CA, C=US
  [certificate is valid from 4/25/01 3:00 AM to 4/25/20 3:00 AM]
  [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]

  [entry was signed on 5/11/17 3:31 AM]
  X.509, CN=Legion of the Bouncy Castle Inc., OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Oracle Corporation
  [certificate is valid from 3/10/17 8:07 PM to 3/10/22 8:07 PM]
  X.509, CN=JCE Code Signing CA, OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Oracle Corporation
  [certificate is valid from 7/6/16 7:48 PM to 12/30/30 7:00 PM]
  [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]

    8546 Thu May 11 17:31:20 EDT 2017 META-INF/BC1024KE.SF
    2221 Thu May 11 17:31:20 EDT 2017 META-INF/BC1024KE.DSA
    8546 Thu May 11 17:31:18 EDT 2017 META-INF/BC2048KE.SF
    6365 Thu May 11 17:31:18 EDT 2017 META-INF/BC2048KE.DSA
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/mail/
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/handlers/
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/util/
       0 Thu May 11 17:30:54 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/validator/
       sm       715 Thu May 11 17:27:56 EDT 2017 org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/CMSProcessableBodyPart.class

  X.509, CN=Legion of the Bouncy Castle Inc., OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Sun Microsystems Inc
  [certificate is valid from 3/10/17 8:15 PM to 4/25/20 3:00 AM]
  X.509, CN=JCE Code Signing CA, OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Sun Microsystems Inc, L=Palo Alto, ST=CA, C=US
  [certificate is valid from 4/25/01 3:00 AM to 4/25/20 3:00 AM]
  [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]

  [entry was signed on 5/11/17 3:31 AM]
  X.509, CN=Legion of the Bouncy Castle Inc., OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Oracle Corporation
  [certificate is valid from 3/10/17 8:07 PM to 3/10/22 8:07 PM]
  X.509, CN=JCE Code Signing CA, OU=Java Software Code Signing, O=Oracle Corporation
  [certificate is valid from 7/6/16 7:48 PM to 12/30/30 7:00 PM]
  [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]
  .
  .
  .
  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

  jar verified.

  Warning:
  This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
  This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2020-04-25) or after any future revocation date.
```

Answer (score 0):

BouncyCastle signs the JAR only with their special code signing certificate for security providers. This is necessary in order to use the JAR as security provider in Java. BouncyCastle doesn't sign the JAR for using e.g. in applets or WebStart. If you need to use it e.g. in applets or WebStart, you need to sign the JAR **additionally** with your public certificate.