# how do I set keystore path in my java program in powershell script or cmd?

Tags: java, powershell, cmd, keystore

We use a CMD to call a Powershell script. In the powershell script, a Java program is called. Both files are in the same directory. In that directory is also a keystore file (zzzz.keystore) available that needs to be used by the java program. I know this can be done via -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=

I have used many ways of setting the path but all of them return error: "Could not find or load main class .net.ssl.trustStore=zzzz.keystore"

This is on a windows system. I'm not sure if I have to set something in the cmd that calls the powershell script to make it work. Please advice.

I have found this question: [java SSL and cert keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore) but there is no explicit example of the path set in windows. I have used these ways to add the path within the powershell script but none do work:

```
& java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=zzzz.keystore com.router.router.router.Router

& java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="zzzz.keystore" com.router.router.router.Router

& java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/path/to/file/zzzz.keystore" com.router.router.router.Router

& java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C://path//to//file//zzzz.keystore" com.router.router.router.Router

& java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\\path\\to\\file\\zzzz.keystore" com.router.router.router.Router

& java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/path/to/file/zzzz.keystore com.router.router.router.Router

& java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C://path//to//file//zzzz.keystore com.router.router.router.Router
```

Cmd file contains:

```
SET CLASSPATH=.\yyyyy.jar
powershell .\startscript.ps1
```

startscript.ps1

```
& java followed by script as shown above followed by parameters for Java object
```

I expect java to run without errors. I receive again and again java.exe : Error: Could not find or load main class .net.ssl.trustStore=zzzz.ke
ystore

I know the keystore is good as it is used in other scripts where everything is set and called within the cmd script, there is no powershell involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because PowerShell sees the `-` in front of the java `D` switch, and thinks "oh, a parameter name".

Prevent PowerShell from parsing it as a command parameter with `--%`:

```
& java --% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\\path\\to\\file\\zzzz.keystore" com.router.router.router.Router
```

or by either quoting or grouping the argument strings:

```
& java '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\\path\\to\\file\\zzzz.keystore"' com.router.router.router.Router
# or 
& java @('-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\\path\\to\\file\\zzzz.keystore"', 'com.router.router.router.Router')
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed code in Powershell to:

```
& java '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="zzzz.keystore"' com.router.router.router.Router
```

Now the java program runs without a problem