# Where does Java look in Windows for SSL certificates?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, jsse

I am running Java 8 on Windows 10.   I have a security subfolder under my JAVA_HOME and can see the `cacerts` file there.   However, I am trying to call a remote service which requires a client certificate.  I have the required client certificate as a .jks file but do not know how to put it in place so that Java will pick it up when making the service call.

I have tried copying the .jks file into the same directory as the cacerts but it did not work (restarting the Java VM, of course).  I also tried using the keytool to export from the .jks file into a .cer file and then importing the .cer file into cacerts but I hit a permissions issue there.

I have turned on javax debugging (`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`) so I can see what certificates are found.

So, how do I get Java to find my certificates?

Comment: In your keystore. There is no default. You can tell Java where it is via `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=`. See the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: Force the keystore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore

Comment: And to be clear, JRE/lib/security/cacerts is (normally) used for the _truststore_ which is used to check the _server_ cert, not to supply the client cert. Java uses the keystore _format_ (JKS) for both the keystore and truststore _data_, which are different.