# GraalVM windows native-image installation Problem

Tags: windows, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to install native-image for my GraalVM in Windows environment. In cmd, I used the below command,

```
gu install native-image
```

But it shows this error,

> Downloading: Release index file from oca.opensource.oracle.com
>
> Error: Error reading component list: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: It might be that your organization has got a man-in-the-middle SSL firewall product.  This would require that browsers have root certificates for this firewall, but Java (and GraalVM) has its own set of certificates which may not have been updated.  Try running the gu command outside your corporate firewall if possible/allowed.

Comment: try pointing  JAVA_HOME to GraalVM

Answer (score 0):

As the error states your environment from which `gu` is estabilishing a secure connection to the remote repository cannot verify the certification path of the repository. In other words your JVM does not trust `oca.opensource.oracle.com`.

The `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` file contains the collection of trusted CA used by JVM when running `gu`. Apparently this file in your JDK is missing the certificate chain of your repository.

---

#### Adding new trusted certificate

1. Download `oca.opensource.oracle.com` repository's root certificate.
2. Open `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` file in elevated mode with e.g. [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) or modify it with [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html). Default password is `changeit`.
3. Add new trusted CA from 1.
4. Save and close.

#### Useful sources

- [SSL and cert keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871352/7394988)
- [Difference Between a Java Keystore and a Truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference)

In our organization the issue was in the man-in-the-middle SSL firewall product as mentioned [by prunge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035433/graalvm-windows-native-image-installation-problem#comment125694491_71035433).

Answer (score 0):

Add the public certificates to trust store just run below commands.

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername gds.oracle.com -connect gds.oracle.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > gds.oracle.com.crt
keytool -import -alias gds.oracle.com -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file gds.oracle.com.crt -storepass changeit

echo | openssl s_client -servername graalvm.org -connect graalvm.org:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > graalvm.org.crt
keytool -import -alias graalvm.org -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -file graalvm.org.crt  -storepass changeit
```