# Receiving a "no mqjbnd in java.library.path" exception when starting Springboot IBMQ application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to IBM MQ. I've read in multiple docs that this line should help prevent it:

```java
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

But in my case it doesn't. Anyone knows how to fix this and what the actual problem is?

```java
    import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
    import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
    import com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.*;
    import com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.CommonConstants;
    
    import javax.net.ssl.*;
    import java.security.KeyStore;

    @Bean
    public JmsComponent mq() {
        JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
        jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
        return jmsComponent;
    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        try {
           
            //keystore is being fetched here
            String keystoreKey = "${keyStorePassword}";
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("${keyStore}"),
                    keystoreKey.toCharArray());

            // Create key manager
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keystoreKey.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();


            // Create trust manager
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            trustManagerFactory.init(KeyStore.getInstance(trustStore, trustStorePassword));
            TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

            // Initialize SSLContext
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
            sslContext.init(km, tm, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);

            MQEnvironment.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }
}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```java
    org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$2: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8598: Failed to load the IBM MQ native JNI library: 'mqjbnd'.
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:184) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:510) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:572) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:425) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:392) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:159) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:172) ~[camel-core-processor-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:475) ~[camel-core-processor-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.executeReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:196) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:164) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:163) ~[camel-core-processor-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:379) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:208) ~[camel-timer-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76) ~[camel-timer-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516) ~[na:na]
    Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:334) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8653) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8023) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:242) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6026) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:200) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$2: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8598: Failed to load the IBM MQ native JNI library: 'mqjbnd'.
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1167) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:307) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:262) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:224) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1249) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:230) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:765) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:699) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8645) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path: /Users/user/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1140) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
    
    2023-07-19T10:39:05.986+02:00  WARN 59061 --- [timer://mytimer] o.a.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer  : Error processing exchange. Exchange[F460175233ACADD-0000000000000000]. Caused by: [org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException - Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$2: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8598: Failed to load the IBM MQ native JNI library: 'mqjbnd'.]
    
    org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$2: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8598: Failed to load the IBM MQ native JNI library: 'mqjbnd'.
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:184) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:510) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:572) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:425) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:392) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:159) ~[camel-jms-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:172) ~[camel-core-processor-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:475) ~[camel-core-processor-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.executeReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:196) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:164) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:163) ~[camel-core-processor-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:379) ~[camel-base-engine-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:208) ~[camel-timer-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76) ~[camel-timer-4.0.0-RC1.jar:4.0.0-RC1]
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516) ~[na:na]
    Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:334) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8653) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8023) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:322) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:242) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6026) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:200) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497) ~[spring-jms-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$2: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8598: Failed to load the IBM MQ native JNI library: 'mqjbnd'.
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1167) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:307) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:262) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:224) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1249) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:230) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:765) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:699) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8645) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path: /Users/user/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989) ~[na:na]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1140) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Instead of all the code for the key store why not set the java system properties to point to the key store and let MQ pick it up from there.  The java system properties are documented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/ssl-and-cert-keystore/5871352#5871352).  I world recommend you set them with `System.setProperties()` method so that you do not expose the password on the command line.

Comment: Those mqjbnd are usually part of the stacktace due to MQ checking for the mqjbnd library to determine if there is a local MQ server install. I would suggest capturing a full JMS trace and reviewing that for the actual cause. Trace inductions can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=tmcja-collecting-mq-classes-jms-trace-by-using-java-system-property).