# Error when trying to connect through SSL. Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keytool

I am totally new to `web services`. I am tying to connect through `SSL` connection. I followed this site: [SSLHandshakeException: PKIX: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html) , this thread [How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error) and I did add the `certificate` to the `keystore` as follow:

```
keytool -importcert -alias <some name> -file <Certifacate path> -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

and I checked it is exists by using `keytool -list` command

The problem is that I got this error message when I trying to connect through `SSL` in the application:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I also tried to add the `trustStore` location and password in the application as follow:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

But still got the same error.

I am using `Jdeveloper 11g R1` and `JDK 7`, if that's help.

---

**Update:**

After further reading some solutions said I need to make this path:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\lib\security\cacerts`

As `truststore`

I replace the above java statement to be as follow:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_09\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

but still I am getting the same error !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting error: PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388279/getting-error-pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification-pat)

Comment: @WarrenDew I already did that as I describeed in the question

Comment: Setting javax.net.ssl.trustStore to the JRE default is what already happens by default. You don't need to do it at all. As long as you imported the certificate into the correct cacerts file, and told the keytool to trust it as a CA certificate, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

After I got the certificate form third party I did the following:

1. Adding the certificate to the trusted root certificate in the browser with server Authentication check form the `advance option`.
2. Adding the certificate to the trust certificate using `keytool` options in the `command prompt` refer to this link: [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore) for mor information.

After long search I found that the cause of the problem `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`  as follow:  (**Note: that's what I found out there may be more**)

**a. There is a missing intermediate certificates that is not added.**

to solve this issue you need to add the root certificate and all the other will be added by default. To find out the certificate used by your third party refer to the following links. Basically, the proposed solution will provide you with a java class called (`InsertCert.java`) that will provide you with the certificates used by the server. what do you need is to pass the `host name` as a parameters. Find the details in the following links:

- [No more 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target)
- [Step by step video to solve the issue using information from the provisos link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPRdfw_yfv8)

**b .You are adding the certificate in the wrong cacerts file.**

To solve this issue refer to the same java class mentioned earlier (`InsertCert.java`) and it will provide with the correct `cacerts` path in my case I am using `Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7` and the path is:

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\JDeveloper\JDeveloper11117\jdk160_24\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```