# Intermittent - SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

I wrote a java client to connect to Ldap over ssl.
I imported CA certificates to my java key store and I am able to connect Ldap over ssl and pull information. The problem is it is not working always. Often it throws:CommunicationException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed. If I re run again (with out changing anything) it works.

This issue killing me for days, as a work around I am catching this exception and retrying. But I am looking for a permanent fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code where I get the context:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, securityCredential);
        env.put("java.naming.provider.url", url);
        return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
```

Strack Trace:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: adapps.nms.comm:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:215)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2685)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:306)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:240)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:151)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getLdapContext(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:149)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getUserByNTID(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:97)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.main(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1682)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:257)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:251)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1168)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1175)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:805)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:94)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:820)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:324)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:224)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1147)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:197)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:255)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:319)
        ... 18 more
CommunicationException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: adapps.nms.com:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:215)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2685)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:306)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:240)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:151)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getLdapContext(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:149)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getUserByNTID(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:97)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getUserByNTID(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:109)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.main(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1682)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:257)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:251)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1168)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1175)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:657)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:108)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:409)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:352)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:210)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:324)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:224)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1147)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:197)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:255)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:319)
        ... 37 more
CommunicationException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: adapps.nms.com:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:215)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2685)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:306)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:240)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:151)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getLdapContext(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:149)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getUserByNTID(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:97)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getUserByNTID(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:109)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.getUserByNTID(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:109)
        at NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.main(NMSLdapServiceDAOImpl.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1682)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:257)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:251)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1168)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:609)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:545)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1175)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:657)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:108)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:409)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:352)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:210)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:324)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:224)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1147)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:197)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:255)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:319)
        ... 38 more
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace (at least up to the point where it gets into your own code).

Comment: Did `url` involve DNS entry that often changes? Is your network connection stable, no network drops? Was there any 3rd party software detecting your program as malicious -- hence blocking file / network I/O?

Comment: @DavidMoles .. thanks for your quick reply..updated my question with complete stack trace..

Comment: @gerrytan .. thanks for quick reply..I dont think there is any network glitch or something that sort, it works perfectly when I dont use ssl

Comment: possible duplicate of [PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062307/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested)

Comment: @DavidMoles .. I already imported the certificates to my JRE cacerts file.Also I am able to connect using ssl.. problem is if it works for 1 minute..it wont work for next 1 minute.then again starting working for next 1 mins..

Comment: Was there any clustering / load balancing involved? Your request might work against one node but not the other due to missing / incorrect trust certs

Comment: @gerrytan.. good point.. thanks..I will investigate on this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should import certificate of the server:port to java JRE keystore for example for following server and port:

  ```
  serverAddress: myserver.mydomain.com
  serverPort: 443
  keystore password is default: changeit
  ```
- First of all, check $JAVA_HOME and java executable before continue, you should be sure about the choosing correct JAVA_HOME for importing , if you have different ones:

  ```
  $ ~/bin$ echo $JAVA_HOME
  /opt/jdk
  $ ~/bin$ which java
  /usr/bin/java
  $ ~/bin$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 May 10  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
  $ ~/bin$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jun  6  2014 /etc/alternatives/java -> /opt/jdk/bin/java
  $ ~/bin$ java -version
  java version "1.8.0_05"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
  $ ~/bin$ `which java` -version
  java version "1.8.0_05"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
  $ ~/bin$   $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
  java version "1.8.0_05"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
  ```
- Extracting certificate from the server:

  ```
  $ openssl s_client -connect <serverAddress:serverPort> 2>&1 < "/" | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/myserver.crt
  ```

  For this example `<serverAddress:serverPort>` should be replaced with `myserver.mydomain.com:443`
- The extracted file should be look like as follows:

  ```
  $ cat /tmp/myserver.crt
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  blahblahblahaC5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCd
  ME22AKpyBPIRbTwTBedJz/KFtwCAxO2jXIcIob99LXv8W4KMOJgazn2UUBm/azZ1
  z+9qhq3UeIy8Z58WK2N5l/SI7s3+bkii/dnpW3Akw8OyXABnN1EyfwnL607POqXm
  blahblahblah
    ...Certificate Data is variable for each server address...
  blahblahblah
  blahblahblahT9p1jar2vxoHv3/dSwKoeLL8XpkmVx9oVUZ3XuICPvEmu8eBfOEm
  ZXNlYXJjaC5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCd4I7L
  ME22AKpyBPIRbTwTBedJz/KFtwCAxO2jXIcIob99LXv8W4KMOJgazn2UUBm/azZ1
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  ```
- You need to import the extracted certificate into JRE keystore:

  ```
  $ keytool -import -alias myserverCert -file  /tmp/myserver.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
  ```
- You can check that the certification existence in java JRE keystore or not after the import:

  ```
   $ keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
  ```
- Default password for java JRE keystore is

  **changeit**
- For applying the changes you need to **restart** the java JVM.
- After finish you can remove the temporary file if you had created it in a non temporary place:

  ```
  $ rm /tmp/myserver.crt
  ```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the problem was intermittent.