# Javamail - Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp

I'm trying to send email from my java and I couldn't connect to my host.
Here my codes:

```
public class sendEmail implements Runnable{
     @Override
     public void run(){
        try{
            final String username = "user", password = "pass", from = "from@mail.com", to = "to@mail.com";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", username);
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "mail.host.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); 
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            session.setDebug(true);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            try{
                msg.setSubject("Test SMTP");
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
                Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                transport.connect("mail.itbuntuksemua.com", username, password);
                transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                transport.close();
                System.out.println("Done");
            }catch(MessagingException | NumberFormatException | HeadlessException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(UnknownHostException | NumberFormatException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
 }
```

and here my `SMTPAuthenticator()` codes:

```
private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username = "user"; 
        String password = "pass";
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    } 
}
```

and here again, my report bugs :

> DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
>   DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
>   DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
>   DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.host.com", port 465, isSSL true
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.host.com, port: 465;
>     nested exception is:
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
>       at scam.ccChecker$sendEmail.run(ccChecker.java:186)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:957)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:892)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:211)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1460)
>       ... 16 more
>   Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
>       ... 22 more

can someone help me? :(

Comment: It looks like (at a guess), they're using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062307/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested)

Comment: It is possible that you don't have the certificate for that mail server.

Comment: what is certificate? I was tried from PHP Mailer and my smtp run as well. when I tried from my java, it couldn't connect to my smtp

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try downloading the certificate, install it using keytool, then set them as system variables. Here's how:

1. Go to URL in your firefox browser, click on HTTPS certificate chain (next to URL address). Click `"more info" > "security" > "show certificate" > "details" > "export.."`. Pickup the name and choose file type `example.der`. Now you have file with keystore and you have to add it to your JVM
2. Locate the file `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
3. Import the `example.der` file into the `cacerts` file using the following:

   ```
   sudo keytool -import -alias example -keystore  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file example.der
   ```
4. The default keystore password is '`changeit`'
5. You can view the change that you made with this command that shows the Certificate fingerprint.

   ```
   keytool -list -keystore cacerts
   ```
6. If this doesn't solve the problem, try adding these java options as arguments:

   ```
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit"
   ```
7. Or you can put them in as system variables in your java code:

   ```
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");
   ```

More instructions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/1696153

Comment: thanks for answer, i use this one `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","*");` and its works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to set certificate, to access the SMTP port. Something like that:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","key");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
```

Comment: how do i get `trustStore` key?

Comment: You need to generate it. There are articles how to do that.

Comment: I got this (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html) . but I dont understand