# fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxx.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using a jupyter notebook in the cloud and I want to push my jupyter notebooks into gitlab.

I ran the following commands in the folder:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://xxx.git
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master
```

After the last command, I got the error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
```

So I ran

```
git show-ref
```

This showed three refs

refs/heads/main

refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

refs/remotes/origin/main

Trying

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

gave the error about failed certificate verification.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you have set yourself up to have a branch named `main` instead of a branch named `master`. *The branch names you use are unimportant to Git itself.* Use whichever one(s) you like. But if you plan to continue with the name `main`, run `git push origin main` to send your commits to GitHub and ask GitHub to create or update the name `main` on their side. Use `git push origin HEAD:master` to send the commits, regardless of which name *you* are using, and ask GitHub to create or update the name `master` on their side. There's no need to use the same names on each side, but ...

Comment: ... but humans normally do that because otherwise it's too confusing for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't have a trusted TLS<sup>1</sup> certificate in the server where you're hosting your GitLab instance.

Personally I would recommend you that you use trusted certificates, since the ones from **Let's Encrypt** are totally free, but in any case you can disable TLS<sup>1</sup> verification for a single command:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false push origin -u
```

Or (**don't do that and use trusted cerficates**) disable it at all for all the repositories:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

<sub>*1: TLS is new (not so new) replacement for SSL.</sub>

> Transport Layer Security (TLS), the successor of the now-deprecated Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), is a cryptographic protocol designed to provide communications security over a computer network.
>
> *- Wikipedia, Transport Layer Security [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)*

Comment: Using `--global` for git-config but describing it as "for a given repository" → really?

Comment: Sorry, that was a problem with my English. I wanted to say to disable it for all given repositories. Thank you for noticing, I'll change it now.

Comment: FYI: You can just drop the `--global` flag so the setting is applied to a single local repository, where it'd be stored in `.git/config` of that repo instead of `~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Why disable ou bypass security ?

I found the problem. In my Nginx configuration, I had to provide "fullchain" certificate. Example:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

Or for Apache configuration, check an older post here: [PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062307/pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested/72099708#72099708)